# How to add SerDe parameters in CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-cdk, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am using CDK to create a Glue table like this:

```js
  const someTable = new Glue.Table(
      scope,
      "some-table",
      {
        tableName: "some-table",
        columns: [
          {
            name: "value",
            type: Glue.Schema.DOUBLE,
          },
          {
            name: "user_id",
            type: Glue.Schema.STRING,
          },
        ],
        partitionKeys: [
          {
            name: "region_id",
            type: Glue.Schema.BIG_INT,
          },
        ],
        database: glueDb,
        dataFormat: Glue.DataFormat.PARQUET,
        bucket: props.bucket,
      }
    );
```

It looks like this this is creating my Glue table as expected, but it's also doing some things behind the scenes like setting up a a Serde serialization lib (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe). For my use case, I have to also specify some Serde parameters in the table configuration, but I can't find how to do it in the CDK documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-glue.Table.html) even though it looks like something you can configure in the console under "Edit Table".

[image]

Has anyone run into this and have any suggestions about how to update this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass serde settings to a [Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-glue-alpha-readme.html) (`@aws-cdk/aws-glue-alpha`) using the `dataFormat` (type of [DataFormat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-glue-alpha.DataFormat.html)) prop.

```js
// TableProps
{
  dataFormat:  glue.DataFormat.PARQUET
}
```

For finer-grained control, use the L1 [CfnTable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_glue.CfnTable.html) (`aws-cdk-lib`) construct, whose API matches the CloudFormation [`AWS::Glue::Table`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-table.html) resource.

```js
// CfnTableProps
tableInput: {
  // ...
  storageDescriptor: {
    inputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat',
    outputFormat: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat',
    serdeInfo: {
      serializationLibrary: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe',
      parameters: { 'serialization.format': 1 },
    },
```